# symbolic link a source folder and save files in the target folder

Tags: linux, symbolic-link

I want to make a symbolc link from source Folder to Target Folder, such that all the files that are directed to be saved in source Folder should be saved in Target folder. Such that the files are actually stored in Target folder and only there symlinks are created in the source folder

Comment: so yeah, thats basically how symlinks work. the only thing I'd point out is you don;t link a directory to a target. in the source location you create a link to the target, and that creates a thing that's like a directory, but is actually a link. so you would use a command like `ln -s \path\to\a\directory\that\doesn't\exist\yet \path\to\target`. if you already have a directory with the same name at the source, delete it before running the command. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-linux-using-the-ln-command/#creating-symlinks-to-a-directory

Comment: @FrankThomas The command in your comment is misleading: (1) Backslashes. What? (2) The existing target should be specified first. My method to remember this is `cp foo bar`, where `foo` must exist and `bar` is a new name. `ln` is similar. (3) `/path/to/a/directory/that/doesn't/exist/yet` is misleading because `/path/to/a/directory/that/doesn't/exist/` must exist.

Comment: The edit changes a lot. Why do you need such contraption? Why is a symlink to the target directory not enough? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here.

Comment: Model checkpointing is saving to my local directory on cluster, and I have a memory restriction of 10GB on local directory. I want to store checkpointing on my work_directory, so If I create a symlink from .locale/workspace/checkpoints to my WRKDIR then my file with be automatically transfered to WRKDIR and I will have symlinks in .locale/workspace/checkpoints, This location is referenced later in the code (why not edit the code? because the software architect recommends to the code as it is)

Comment: " If I create a symlink from `.locale/workspace/checkpoints` to my WRKDIR then my file with be automatically transfered to WRKDIR and I will have symlinks in `.locale/workspace/checkpoints`" -- If you create a symlink to WRKDIR then you won't have symlinks in it (unless there are or will be symlinks in WRKDIR). Have you tried to create a symlink to the directory and see how it works? You keep writing about symlinks in the (symlinked???) directory. Again: why is symlink to the target directory not enough?